# Xpath expression returns null

Tags: xpath, href, extract

I have the plenty of links like this:

```
<a href="/edit_flat/1674093.html"><b>Edit issue &gt;&gt;</b></a>
```

Trying to extract the href' content I use Xpath expression:

```
//a[contains(@href,'/edit_flat')]
```

but it returns me null. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//a[contains(@href,'/edit_flat')]` selects `a` elements anywhere in the document tree that have an `href` attribute containing the '/edit_flat' string.

These matching elements do have this very "href" attribute, but the XPath expression you are using returns "only" the `a` elements, if there are any.

To actually return the matching elements' attribute's values, you need an extra step, with `/` and `@href`. So what you want is:

```
//a[contains(@href,'/edit_flat')]/@href
```

**Suggestion:**

What you really want is probably to select links which `href` begin with the substring "/edit_flat", so it's safer to use:

```
.//a[starts-with(@href,'/edit_flat')]/@href
```